# Excel formula is doing the calculation, but still displaying the first answer in the cell

Tags: excel, cell, formula

Pulling my hair out over this. When I use the drag button on my selection to copy the formula down relatively, it will correctly alter the formula to go one row down, but will still display the wrong answer in the cell. I'm unable to post an image due to my low rep(I'm a long time lurker, new poster), but please find a link to the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gR4y.png

The formula for that cell is:

```
=MROUND(B21,"1:00")
```

Which is basically rounding the hour to the nearest hour.

However, as you can see, the cell shows the answer '10:00' which is wrong, it should be '09:00'.

Now the real part that throws me is, if I click in the formula box at the top as if I was going to edit the formula, and then press enter to leave the box the cell then corrects itself to what it should be! It's as if when I drag the formula down, it puts the formula in the box but doesn't actually calculate it until it thinks I'm changing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if this is a confusing post :)

Comment: For me, it works and it shows correctly "9:00" for the value "9:25:31". Are you sure the "calculation" is not set to Manual?

Comment: DataSmarter - thanks! I found the 'Calculation' button, and it was indeed set to manual. Changing it to automatic fixed this. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given as a response to my post by DataSmarter.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOiJx.png

Clicking this 'Calculation Options' button given on the 'Formulas' tab, and selecting the 'Automatic' option fixed this issue.

Thanks for your help, everybody!

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe is odd. Note:

> MROUND rounds up, away from zero, if the remainder of dividing number by multiple is greater than or equal to half the value of multiple.

from [here](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/MROUND-function-86dc90eb-1e0e-4e03-8913-6debe3f18c5f?CorrelationId=50fc9e8f-bca8-4599-a63b-1a476f5c4be6&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB). I suggest you try [FLOOR](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/floor.php).